# how to rename a page which is present in multiple locations in under the page

Tags: groovy

I have change the page name from au-op to auop which is the main page but under the page there are lot of sub pages where the name of the page as displaying as au-op in different fields. now i want to change the page from au-op to auop from all content with groovy script. can anyone help me from these.

Comment: "now i want to change the page from au-op to auop from all content with groovy script" - Can you elaborate on what that means and what your challenge is?

Comment: To be clear, what you are being asked to do is [edit] this question and tell us what you want to do, show what you tried, and show what results you get.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
s = s.replace('au-op', 'auop')
```